# How do I migrate a VS Code installation on WSL to portable mode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux, vscode-remote

Official documentation provided for VSCode Portable [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/portable) only indicates how to get it working for Windows, Linux and Mac.

On a Windows machine, I also use VSCode within WSL and notice that there are user/configuration files of VSCode at

`\\wsl$\Ubuntu-20.04\home\Tryer\.vscode-server` and this has subfolders `\bin\`, `\data\` and `\extensions\` The documentation does not indicate how to migrate these file to portable mode.

How can one use Portable VSCode, then, on WSL ?

---

Edited to add: On the github page, a suggested solution is [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/145854#issuecomment-1076076314)

However, it is not clear to me why this should work. The address: `AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code/bin` is the directory of the full installation. I would imagine that the portable Windows VSCode installation and `code.exe` would be in places other than `AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code/bin` . This, in my limited understanding seems to be the idea of Portable VSCode -- install in a user defined personal and nonsystem directory.

Comment: you can't just follow the migration steps for linux? https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/portable#_migrate-to-portable-mode

Comment: @starball on pure linux box the directory structure is different from how WSL's VSCode installation is. In the latter, one does not need a "full fledged" installation. The WSL VSCode is "parisitic" on the native Windows installation. For e.g., they share `keybindings.json`, and snippet json files. With what you are suggesting, I would need to treat WSL as a pure Linux box and install separate keybindings, snippet files, etc. That seems repetitive and liable to break and gives more headache. Ideally, the portabls WSL should be parasitic on the portable Windows installation, in my expectation.

Comment: @starball The extensions installed in Windows are automatically "visible"/installed in WSL VSCode too. If I understand what you are suggesting, one would have to install the same extension twice -- one in portable Windows and in portable Linux but on the WSL side of things, is this not the case?